# PHP getenv results in MAC address not IP

Tags: php, unique, getenv

New so maybe a problem with correct use however;

Developing a php /web based ordering system needing to identify device (browser) when placing order. Currently using getenv:

```
 $terminal = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Majority of results as expected - Device IP. Occasionally with unexpected results of MAC address not IP.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and/or combinations of

> getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')

don't seem to provide a different result.

IP address is set manually so is there a better / correct (?) way to uniquely identify the device / user?

Probably something obvious but any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: probably a ipv6 address... which will look like a mac address

Comment: Champion Orangepill! Knew it would be something obvious and way toooo obvious it was! Thanks a heap for looking and replying. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a MAC address it is an IPV6 Address which looks a whole lot like a MAC address.